# How to Cache response in ajax to avoid http call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have created a tabbed-layout for my website. Clicking on each tab takes you to another page. I want to avoid a new HTTP post call every time the user switches between the tabs. How can I do this? The solution must be a JS-based solution.

Comment: Set a flag on the tab to indicate that data has already been loaded. Check that flags state before making each request.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Create div for each tab.
2. load your ajax responce on respective div by using :
$(<respectivedivselector>).load(<url>,<data>,<calbackfunction>(){});
```

This way your ajax responce will be automatically be cached on div..

You can also set ajax cache globally as

```
$.ajaxSetup ({

    cache: true
});
```

you can also set this attribute to individual ajax call as

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/YourURL",
    cache: true,
    .
    .
    .
    success: function(data) {
        $(<respectivedivselector>).html(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [beforeLoad](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeLoad) event to prevent the tab from loading content that has already been loaded.

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    beforeLoad: function(event, ui) {
        //If contents are already loaded
        if(ui.panel.contents().length > 0){
            return false; //Prevent tab from loading
        }
    }
});
```